# TypeError: path.merge is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm using d3 (version 7.0.0) to draw several graphs in a browser page using ReactJS. I have managed to draw the data lines, but when I try to draw the axis it returns an error.

The error is the following:

```
TypeError: path.merge is not a function
    at Array.axis (axis.js:59)
    at Array.push../node_modules/d3/d3.js.d3_selectionPrototype.call (d3.js:975)
    at InstantAnTr.js:219
```

This is the code I use to import the modules:

```js
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale'
import { axisBottom,axisLeft } from 'd3-axis'
import { line } from 'd3-shape'
var d3 = require("d3")
```

And this is the code I am using to draw the axis on the graph.

```js
var x = scaleLinear().domain([0,t]).nice().range([margin.left,width-margin.right])
var y = scaleLinear().domain([-1,1]).nice().range([height-margin.top,margin.bottom])
var xAxis = axisBottom(x)
var yAxis = axisLeft(y)
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform",`translate(0,${height/2})`)
    .call(xAxis)
    .call(g=>g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g=>g.selectAll(".tick line").clone()
    .attr("y2",-height)
    .attr("stroke-opacity",0.1))
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform",`translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(yAxis)
    .call(g=>g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g=>g.select(".tick line").clone()
    .attr("x2",width)
    .attr("stroke-opacity","0.1"))
```

Any suggestions on what is wrong here?

Comment: Did you try and strip out the stuff formatting the axes and ensure the issue is with just drawing a basic axis; and for that matter isolate to either the x- or y-axis being the issue?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I tried to just write ```svg.append("g").call(xAxis)``` and ```svg.append("g").call(xAxis)```, but it returned the same error. It also happens when I only leave ```svg.append("g").call(yAxis)```. The problem happens when I try to make the call to ```xAxis``` or ```yAxis```.